# Instagram Login (Login with Facebook also) integration in android project

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I want to integrate Instagram into my app. but, I can't find code which successfully login every time. I followed this document (http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/instagram-integration-android-application-tutorial) It was working before 5 months but not working properly now.  When I log in then **Progress bar** loading for two to three minutes but I don't get any response. If I choose **login with facebook** then it gives **Login failed** Error and Sometimes **Progress bar** loading and don't get any response. Please, suggest me.

Comment: I am also integrating Instagram, some days ago login working well, but when i checked it today, when i login through Instagram first time , i enter user name and password after that only progress bar is loading nothing happen , but when i kill the app and login again through Instagram again then its working well, any one know Why Instagram loading first time for infinite time and after kill app same code working well and login success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solutions, may it help to others,

Please add following line in your InstagramDialog  class

```
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSavePassword(false);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
```

Following line is important,

```
   webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

enable this option after that Instagram working fine.

I would imagine it is disabled by default for space savings and security.
Hope this help to many developers.
If you have same issue then accept this answeres.